# Why will this not display?

Tags: java, arrays, file-io

It won't display the line of code that has the word put in it.
I want it to display the line of code that contains the substring "put", case insensitive. The first and second lines should be printed as they both contains the substring "put".
Here is the text file:

> Test input.
>
> Put text here.
>
> Not here.
>
> Run it on a computer.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Put {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String firstTextFile = "PROG06.in.txt";
        String secondTextFile = "PRG06.out.txt";
        Scanner Document = null;
        PrintWriter NewFile = null;
        try {
            Document = new Scanner(new File(firstTextFile));
            NewFile = new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream(secondTextFile, true));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Could not find " + firstTextFile);
            System.exit(0);
            System.out.println("Could not find " + secondTextFile);
            System.exit(0);
        }
        while (Document.hasNextLine()) {
            String[] words = Document.nextLine().split(" ");
            List<String> wordList = Arrays.asList(words);
            if (wordList.contains("put")) {
                NewFile.print(wordList);
            }
        }
        Document.close();
        NewFile.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Try `wordList.contains("Put")` not `wordList.contains("put")`

Comment: @jacknad that would work for "put", then, but not "Put", "PUT", or any other upper/lower combination thereof. Nicholas' answer below of using .toLowerCase catches all of the cases.

Answer (score 4):

The line `if (wordList.contains("put")) {` will only match the word 'put', not 'Put'. You either need to do multiple if/else statements for it all, or you need to do a `.toLowercase` on your original string before splitting it.

Comment: Yeah I got that I was testing but the word input has put in it and it will  not display anything.

Comment: Did you want to wordList or nextLine?

Comment: @Logan that's because List.contains("put") will only return true if any element exactly matches "put". "input" does NOT equal "put", and so will not match, nor should it.

Comment: so john what do you suggest that i do to fix it?

Comment: Logan, I was actually a little confused about what you wanted. I thought you only wanted to print a line if it had the word "put" in there, which is different than wanting to print a line if it contains the characters P-U-T in sequence anywhere on the line.

If you want to do the latter, then follow Henry Keiter's answer.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to search for the substring "put", you have to actually do that. Right now, you're just searching your list to see if it contains the individual word. You're not doing yourself any favors by manually splitting up the string; what you really want is a line-by-line substring search. To that end, you'd be much better off simplifying your loop considerably, so you'd have something like this:

```
String line;
while (Document.hasNextLine()) {
    line = Document.nextLine();
    if (line.toLowerCase().contains("put")) {
        // Add the line if "put" appears anywhere in the lowercase version of it.
        NewFile.print(line);
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 for being able to decipher what the OP wanted, and for giving EXTREMELY sleek code.

Comment: it runs but displays nothing in the output

Comment: @Logan You mean the console output? I based my code's output on yours, so the lines with "put" in them get written out to `NewFile`, *not* printed to the screen. If you want the lines to just be printed out (to the console), use `System.out.println(line);`.

Comment: +1, Nice answer... I figured he was looking for the standalone 'put', but this works in all cases if he's looking for any version of p-u-t.

Answer (score 0):

As far as "Test input" not getting processed is concerned

```
        String[] words = Document.nextLine().split(" ");
        List<String> wordList = Arrays.asList(words);
        if (wordList.contains("put")) {  <--  this condition is failing
            NewFile.print(wordList);
        }
```

Now the `words[]` has `{"Test"`, `"Input"}`. You are converting this array to `ArrayList` `wordList`

when you say `wordList.contains("put")`, it checks whether the `ArrayList` has the word `"put"` (and this condition **fails**, because `ArrayList` doesn't have `put`, it has `input` rather).

You should do

```
        String[] words = Document.nextLine().split(" ");
        for(String w : words) {
           if (w.toLowerCase().contains("put")) { <-- this condition should handle all the scenario, including Put, input etc
               NewFile.print(Arrays.asList(words));
           }
        }
```

Comment: Check the section of code that wraps the code you quoted - it's a while loop that iterates through every line. We're looking for a hit on the second line (which has "Put", not the first).

Comment: True, but OP was also concerned about word 'Test input' not getting processed as expected.

Answer (score 0):

A detailed Regex Works for me:

```
   public static void main(String[] args) {
        String firstTextFile = "PROG06.in.txt";
        String secondTextFile = "PRG06.out.txt";

        try{

            LineNumberReader reader = new LineNumberReader(new FileReader(new File("/folder",firstTextFile)));
            PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(new File("/folder",secondTextFile));

            String line = null;
            while ( (line = reader.readLine()) != null){
                if (line.matches(".*\\s[pP][uU][tT]\\s.*")){
                    writer.println(line);
                    writer.flush();
                }
            }

        }catch (IOException eio){
            eio.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Replace file folder paths with your own.